# Capture `this` of caller inside class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code:

```
class Abc {
  funcAbc() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const abc = new Abc();

class Def {
  constructor(func) {
    this.func = func;
  }

  runFunc() {
    this.func();
  }
}

const def = new Def(abc.funcAbc);
def.runFunc();
```

I want `this` to be `Abc` when `runFunc` is called, but in the above implementation, `this` inside `runFunc` refers to `Def`. I understand this is happening because `runFunc` is a member of class `Def`. But is there any way I can capture 'original `this`', i.e. point `this` to `Abc` inside `runFunc`?

I cannot do `const def = new Def(abc.funcAbc.bind(abc)` because the consumer of class should not be bothered about setting the `this` context.

Note: This is not a theoretical question, it is an actual requirement in the project I am working on. The wrapper class takes in config, a part of which is a function. This function can also be a method on a class instance, using `this` inside it. Hence I need to preserve original `this` when calling the function from inside the wrapper class `Def`.

Comment: `I want this to be Abc` - makes no sense for `this` to be the class - oh, did you mean `abc` not `Abc`

Comment: I have similar code in my project, wherein I am taking a method as an input and calling that method from another class after doing some processing.

Comment: *this* is set by how you call a function, or using *bind*. Why would you try to set it as *Abc* when you can just use the identifier *Abc*?

Comment: If you want `this` to be `abc`  then it is `abc.funcAbc.bind(abc)`

Comment: or `const def = new Def(() => abc.funcAbc());`

Comment: can you please clarify ... did you mean `I want this to be Abc` or `I want this to be abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `bind()` (or one of its variants).

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.hello = "hello";
  } 

  run() {
    console.log(this.hello);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(func) {
    this.func = func;
  }
  
  run() {
    this.func();
  }
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B(a.run.bind(a));

b.run();
```

When you `bind()` a function, it locks what `this` will be inside the function when the function is run, regardless of how it is invoked.

You could also wrap up the function in a closure:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.hello = "hello";
    
    this.run = ((self) => () => console.log(self.hello))(this);
  } 
}

class B {
  constructor(func) {
    this.func = func;
  }
  
  run() {
    this.func();
  }
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B(a.run);

b.run();
```

Or you could use the arrow function syntax. Note, this one requires the Babel [class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin to work:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.hello = "hello";
  } 

  run = () => {
    console.log(this.hello);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(func) {
    this.func = func;
  }
  
  run() {
    this.func();
  }
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B(a.run);

b.run();
```

Comment: did you actually read the question? nevermind, but saying "you need to use bind" kinda makes it look like you didn't :p

Comment: I did, though I guess my brain skipped over the "cannot use bind()" bit. However, the other two variants I gave still answer the question as requested I believe.

Comment: yes, they do ... the 2nd one is usable without transpiling in "good" browsers :p

Comment: @samanime: Your solution of using arrow functions is the cleanest so far, but it still assumes that the function being passed to class B is defined as an arrow function. This means that the consumer of class B will have to ensure arrow function implementation. That cannot be always guaranteed and it will be anti-pattern for the api (class B) to depend upon its consumer for its correct behavior.

Comment: In a nutshell, you can't 100% do what you are trying to do in JavaScript. It just isn't possible. The context is based on how the function is either created or invoked. You can't retroactively bind a context after that context has already been lost.

Answer (score 0):

Using `function.call(thisArg, args...)` can set `this` to what ever you want. i.e., you could do:

```
class Abc {
  func() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const abc = new Abc();

class Def {
  constructor(source) {
    this.func = source.func;
    this.source = source;
  }

  runFunc() {
    this.func.call(this.source);
  }
}

const def = new Def(abc);
def.runFunc();
```

This solution assumes there will be a method on `abc` that is called `func`.